# Capturing Snap from Camera using Win RT

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

I am Wrting code to capture image from camera.Below is the code I have written.
    Here method CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync doesnot return.

```
auto MediaCap = ref new Windows::Media::Capture::MediaCapture();

auto ImageProp = ref new Windows::Media::Capture::ImageEncodingProperties ();

ImageProp->Height   = 240;
ImageProp->Width    = 320;
ImageProp->Subtype  = "JPEG";


Windows::Storage::StorageFile^ strFile;
auto res = MediaCap->CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(ImageProp,strFile);

res->Completed = ref new AsyncActionCompletedHandler([](IAsyncAction ^action)
{
    //action->GetResults();
    //action->Start();
    ///action->Close();
});

res->Start();
```

Am I missing something here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue is resolved

I Added code for

1. InitializeAsync()
2. Created file to be used to store image
   using

Windows::Storage::StorageFileRetrievalOperation^ CreateFileOp = Windows::Storage::KnownFolders::PicturesLibrary->CreateFileAsync("Test.jpg");

I found Java script article and implemented in c++.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622/sourcecode?fileId=43837&pathId=1754477665

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to show UI to the user or just silently capture? The only [C++ camera sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Camera-Capture-UI-Sample-0b550324) I've found uses CameraCaptureUI and CaptureFileAsync - then the operation is getting a StorageFile^ back.

If you're deliberately using CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync, check your capabiities.

Comment: My final goal is to write wrapper for WinRT Api.So that any UI application can use the wrapper to Interact with WebCam.I have added WebCam in Capabilities.

Comment: And file system? With a specific file type?